# how can I get colored messages from bash script within GitLab CI

Tags: bash, gitlab

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: Build
  image: alpine:latest
  variables:
    PY_COLORS: '1'
    LOGURU_COLORIZE: "true"
    ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLORS: '1'
  before_script:
    - yum update
  script:
    - bash ./scripts/foobar.sh
...
```

- I have a sample gitlab ci that executes a custom bash script. My goal is to pretty format the echo messages/logs so that they have bold, italics & color. For that, I've tried to use **[tput](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput)** utility for text formatting purposes however the text is rendered without color or formatting!

Here's my sample bash script snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# force tput to use the ansi terminal capabilities
export TERM=ansi

# Margin settings
top=18
bottom=18
left=1.6
right=1.6
pagesize=A4
fontsize=30px

# Text color variables
R=$(tput setaf 1)  # Red
G=$(tput setaf 2)  # Green
C=$(tput setaf 6)  # Cyan
Y=$(tput setaf 3)  # Yellow
P=$(tput setaf 5)  # Purple
RESET=$(tput sgr0) # Reset your text

# convenience functions
function bold {
    tput bold
    echo -n "$@"
}

function ul {
    tput smul
    echo -n "$@"
    tput rmul
}

server_name=$(hostname)

function one() {
    echo ""
    echo "Kernel version on $(bold)${Y}${server_name} ${RESET}is: "
    echo ""
    uname -r
    echo ""
}

function two() {
    echo ""
    echo "CPU load on ${G}${server_name}${RESET} is: "
    echo ""
    uptime
    echo ""
}

main (){
    one
    two
}

main
```

#### Issue/Challenge

- When I execute the bash script locally(macos) I get desired outcome as shown below :

[image: expected-output]

- When the bash script is executed on gitlab ci, it doesn't show formatting. See sample output from gitlab runner :

```
tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address
tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address
....
Kernel version on  is: 
4.14.296-222.539.amzn2.x86_64

CPU load on  is:
```

#### Further Reading:

- Reading other threads e.g [this](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/getting-colorized-output-molecule-and-ansible-on-github-actions-ci) I tried adding below flags `PY_COLORS: '1'` & `ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLORS: '1'` but still no color effect.

Comment: What is this script? How is it used? You don't seem to be using any colors in it. Please [edit] your question and give us some more context. Ideally, provide example input and expected output so we can test.

Comment: @terdon, I've added more context to the question. Also not sure if my question relates to Unix Exchange or Devops Exchange?

Comment: The `tput` error messages are indicating that the script is running in an environment that can't handle the commands required for color. `tput` needs a proper terminal emulator to work correctly, I guess?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's much clearer! What are the logs being displayed in? Is it some sort of web-based interface? As Panki said, it doesn't look like they're actually being shown in a terminal.